# C++ creating a struct from DLL

Tags: c++, dll, struct

I'm using a 3rd party DLL which contains a struct. The corresponding header file contains the struct definition like so:

```
struct MY_STRUCT {
    public:
        MY_STRUCT();

        [members]
}
```

When I try to create a variable of this type:

```
MY_STRUCT myStruct;
```

...I get this error: undefined refference to `MY_STRUCT::MY_STRUCT()`

I am already linking the DLL to my project since I was using some (dynamically loaded) functions from it before.

Comment: Are you familiar with [`__declspec(dllexport)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/exporting-from-a-dll-using-declspec-dllexport)?

Comment: Yes, but this is a 3rd party DLL so the 3rd party is responsible for exporting the structure (if that's what you ment by your comment) and I assume it's properly exported since it's used as a parameter type in one of it's exported functions.

Comment: In that case I would use `dumpbin /exports` on the DLL to see if you can get a hint about how it's exported.

Comment: Have you always been compiling as C++, or were you previously (successfully) compiling as C?

Comment: Always C++ [text to fill min comment length].

Answer (score 1):

So I contacted the DLL provider and their answer was: "The DLL doesn't export any structures, you have to implement them yourself". That's just awesome.